# Uploading a photo from Android with Phonegap

Tags: php, android, cordova, upload, webserver

I am following this [guide](http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/25/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap/comment-page-2/#comment-3089) and have gotten almost everything to work except when I click to submit a photo it just spits an alert back at me with my server code.

This is my code in php:

```
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/public_html/photos".$new_image_name);
```

Is the directory correct or should it be phrased some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure your target directory is an absolute path (is /public_html in the root of your system, or you wanted to define a relative path?).
- Aren't you missing a '/' after photos like so:

  ```
  "/public_html/photos/".$new_image_name
  ```
- Make sure your target directory is writeable for your webserver's user ("www-data" user for instance in LAMP). Set the permissions to be 777 for your "/public_html/photos/" folder if you're not sure and you want to test this.

Comment: so by absolute path you mean that I should do:  "http://www.url.com/public_html/photos"  ?

Comment: no, the server's filesystem full path. If your server runs on linux it could be '/var/www/public_html/photos/' or if you're using Windows 'C:/public_html/photos/'.That's not the URL to the file but the local file path.